# How to get last in-progress process when reopening browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

One "Save" method takes almost 30sec. When save button hit and close the browser after 5sec. Now reopen browser again before finishing last save process and try hit "Save" again.
I want to check last process is still in progress...
This is not related to any user session, browser, anything else. If any user/browser start this Save action again, it should show previous process is still in progress.

How can we achieve this in .net MVC?
Any example will be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Instance id (eg. GUID) must maintain in database, and check every time whenever anyone try to do same operation.